# Problems installing Cloud SQL Proxy on Windows 64-bit

Tags: python, database, windows, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to install Cloud SQL Proxy for Google Cloud Platform on my Windows 10 64 bit OS, so I can use Python scripts to dump data into SQL. I'm following [**this guide**](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) to get it set up.

I created a project and a Google Cloud SQL instance from the Console without any issues, and it shows up in the SDK shell without any problems. After downloading the proxy installer and installing it, a dialog window opens up and then closes before I can read it.

When I go to the Google Cloud SDK shell and try to start the Cloud SQL Proxy with: `cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="[MyInstanceConnectionName]"=tcp:3306`

No matter how many times I try, it throws the error "Cloud Sql Proxy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I already tried re-downloading and re-executing the file but it still won't work.

I have Python 3.6 with Anaconda and Google Cloud SDK shell installed on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: You don't need to execute the cloud_sql_proxy file. You just need to download it, rename it and run the `cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="[MyInstanceConnectionName]"=tcp:3306` command from the folder it's installed in. Or set your System PATH to point to it. Can you confirm you have followed these steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you download the cloud_sql_proxy file make sure to rename it as per instructions in the how to guide. Also make sure you save it in the root directory of where you will run it from. E.g. If you are running the command from C:/users/desktop>.\cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="[YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]"=tcp:3306 then the cloud_Sql_proxy file must be located in the root C drive.

Answer (score 1):

Open PowerShell or whatever terminal you use and navigate to the folder you saved cloud_sql_proxy.exe then add `.\` like so:

```
.\cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="[YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]"=tcp:3306
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and i solved it by adding .\ before
so it would be like this

```
.\cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="[YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]"=tcp:3306
```

and I used PowerShell instead of normal cmd

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder where you save proxy exe file and run following command

> .\{cloud_sql_proxy file name}.exe -instances={projectID}:{zone}:{sql instance name}:{database}=tcp:{port} -credential_file={service account file path}

For instance related detail go to the instance look for "Instance connection name"

Answer (score 0):

Your command is missing `.\` before `cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="[MyInstanceConnectionName]"=tcp:3306`